# Claim rules reference previous claims in ADFS?

Tags: saml, adfs

I'm having trouble getting ADFS to send claim to my app.  The authentication is now completing successfully, but none of the claims we've set in rules are being sent with the response.  I have two rules in this order.

In the first rule, my understanding is the types section is whatever my application is expecting ADFS to output, and doesn't need to correspond to LDAP values.  What is really important is the `query` which must reference valid LDAP attributes.  I am sure the `query` values are valid LDAP attributes, as another working Relying Party configuration uses these same query values(but they use different values in `types` for output).

In the second rule, I am referencing `Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`.  This is not a type in LDAP, but is a reference to the claim created in the first rule.  Am I doing that correctly?  **Can the second rule reference an output type from the first rule?**

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = 
("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"), 
query = ";givenName,sn,mail,employeeI;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Second rule

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", 
Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent", 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/namequalifier"] = "http://somedomain.com/adfs/services/trust", 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "https://someapp.somedomain.com/sp");
```

**Also, is there any reason ADFS wouldn't send claims if the Relying Party is not setup with a certificate for encryption(it is using the IDP certificate to generate signatures/validate)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason claims are not sent is that those AD attributes are null.

You can't use the same claim as input / output.

Take nameidentifier out of the first claim, have a separate claim which outputs something like http://company.com/temp and which is an **add** not an **issue**.

Then use http://company.com/temp as input to the second claim with output http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier.